# Set a sharing pointer to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers

Lets say I have the following:

```
int main() {
    int* test = new int;
    *test = 5;
    int* test2 = test;
}
```

Then, somewhere, in some function , I deallocate memory for `test2` and set it to `NULL`. Is there a way to set `test` to `NULL`, in the same function without passing it to the function?

---

EDIT: `std::shared_ptr` cannot be used

Comment: You would have to pass the variable by references.

Comment: Can you use C++11 at least?

Comment: Use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: No.  It sounds like you might want a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: if you can't use shared_ptr, reinvent shared_ptr

Comment: If test 2 is null, then so is test

Comment: ... or use ``std::unique_ptr`` if you want to make sure there is only one instance holding the pointer. Here, if you passed the value to ``test2``, ``test`` would be automatically empty. This approach would be similar to standard behavior in Rust, where ownership is moved by default rather than copied.

Comment: What's your outer problem? Why would you want to do this? This sounds awful to me. What if code later compares `test` to `NULL`, sees that it is, and concludes that the allocation failed even though it didn't? Whatever actual problem you're trying to solve, there's probably a good way to solve it. But secretly changing values out from under the code isn't it.

Comment: @David Scwartz: What if we have two liked lists that share the same data but have different nodes. When destructor gets invoked for the first list, it deletes the data pointed to and the nodes. When it gets invoked the second time, it cannot check if data pointer is pointing to a valid data and tries to delete it again.

Comment: @Mr.SrJenea: You want `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. If those aren't available to you, make them yourself.

Comment: @Mr.SrJenea As above, we have a perfect solution for that problem, `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`. This is *exactly* what they're for. I doubt we can improve on it. If you can't use them for some reason, about the best you can do is re-implement the parts of them that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` classes do exactly what you want. Since you can't use them, your best option is to re-implement just the portions of them that you need. I'm going to assume you don't need any thread safety and that you don't care about optimizations for simplicity. If you do, use the standard library.

You need a control object. It should have a pointer to the real object and two integers, one the count of strong pointers, the other the count of weak pointers. Strong pointers and weak pointers should have a pointer to the control object.

When a strong pointer is destroyed, decrement the strong pointer count. If the strong pointer count is zero, delete the object and set its pointer to NULL. If the weak pointer count is also zero, discard the control object.

When a weak pointer is destroyed, decrement the weak pointer count. If both pointers counts are zero, discard the control object.

When pointers are copied, you must bump the count. When a weak pointer is promoted to a strong pointer, bump the strong pointer count and fail the operation if it was previously zero.

That should be enough to give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you pass a pointer to a function, you are passing a copy of the value:

```
void f(int* p) {
    // p has the same value as x below, but is independent
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
    // p is null, but back in main 'x' still has the original value
}

int main() {
    int* x = new int;
    f(x);
    // 'x' is unmodified and now points to a deleted block of memory
}
```

Your options are to pass the pointer by reference or pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

void by_pointer(int** p) {
    delete *p;
    *p = nullptr;
}

void by_reference(int*& p) {
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    int* x = new int;
    by_pointer(&x);
    std::cout << (void*)x << "\n";  // outputs null

    int* y = new int;
    by_reference(y);
    std::cout << (void*)y << "\n";  // outputs null
}
```

Comment: *However in modern C++ it's generally better to avoid raw pointers whenever possible* I would not say that.  Owning raw pointers yes, non-owning raw pointers are nothing to get upset about.  They are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the pointer be reference, since a copy would be passed to the function had you used a normal pointer, on which you can only change the pointed value, and since both pointers point to the same thing, no need to call `change()` on both:

```
#include <iostream>

void change(int*& p)
{
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}

int main()
{

    int* test = new int;
    *test = 5;
    int* test2 = test;
    std::cout  << *test; //5
    std::cout << *test2; //5
    change(test);
}
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/900fd7181d7572da)

BTW, I recommend [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for a purpose like this, or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

*EDIT*
The only problem above is that `test2` is deleted, not pointing to `nullptr`, but that cannot be changed unless with smart pointers or a different function.

Comment: Except `test2` is still not null but pointing to deleted memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver that could be solved by having `int*& test2 = test;` initially

Comment: @M.M You could but that changes what the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want this (though I'd **strongly** suggest you to reconsider your design), then the following might work for you:

We wrap the pointer in a structure/class to be able to "hook" us on construction and destruction of such pointers:

```
template<typename T>
struct pointer {
```

Since when freeing the stored value, we also need to modify all `pointer`s that still point to it, we need to keep track of them somehow. I'd say just store them alongside the value:

```
  struct boxing {
    T value;
    std::set<pointer<T> *> references;
  };
  boxing * box;
```

Next comes constructing a pointer. I simplified here. You might want to add perfect forwarding, a possibility to construct a "null pointer", and so on ...

```
  pointer(T value) : box(new boxing{value}) {
    add_myself();
  }
```

As you see, we "add ourselves" (to the set of references). When the `pointer` is destructed, we need to remove ourselves from that set again:

```
  ~pointer() {
    remove_myself();
  }
```

When being copy constructed, we just use the `box` from the original and add ourselves:

```
  pointer(pointer const & p) : box(p.box) {
    add_myself();
  }
```

When being copy assigned to, we first need to remove ourselves from the current `box`, use the box of the original and add ourselves:

```
  pointer & operator=(pointer const & p) {
    remove_myself();
    box = p.box;
    add_myself();
  }
```

I'm lazy. Implement move construction / assignment yourself ;)

```
  pointer(pointer &&) = delete;
  pointer & operator=(pointer &&) = delete;
```

We want to be able to use the `pointer`, so we add a conversion operator to a raw pointer:

```
  operator T*(void) {
    return box ? &(box->value) : nullptr;
  }
```

Finally, freeing a pointer. We set all `box` members of the current `pointers` in the references set to `nullptr` (this includes ourself, thus the additional pointer `b`), and then delete the box:

```
  void free() {
    boxing * b = box;
    for (pointer * p : b->references) {
      p->box = nullptr;
    }
    delete b;
  }
```

Oh, and last but not least, adding and removing ourselves:

```
  private:
  void remove_myself() {
    if (box == nullptr) return;
    box->references.erase(this);
    if (box->references.size() == 0) {
      delete box;
    }
  }
  void add_myself() {
    if (box == nullptr) return;
    box->references.insert(this);
  }
};
```

Some function. Note that I pass by value to force another copy construction:

```
void foo(pointer<int> p) {
  p.free();
}
```

Two `pointers`, pointing to the same boxed value:

```
int main(int, char **) {
  pointer<int> a{21};
  pointer<int> b = a;
  *b = 42;
  std::cout << *a << std::endl;
  foo(a);
  std::cout << "a is " << ((a == nullptr) ? "null" : "non-null") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Above example on ideone.](http://ideone.com/vkymt7)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of shared controllers of a uniquely-owned object is of course horrid (for reasons that will become clear).

Nevertheless, it can be done:

```
template<class T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>>
struct shared_unique
{
    struct control_block
    {
        control_block(Deleter del, T* p) : del_(std::move(del)), ptr_(p), refs_(1) {}

        Deleter del_;
        T* ptr_;
        std::size_t refs_;

        void addref()
        {
            ++refs_;
        }

        void release()
        {
            if (--refs_ == 0)
                delete this;
        }

        ~control_block() {
            if (ptr_)
                del_(ptr_);
        }
    };

    control_block* ctrl_;

    shared_unique(T* p = nullptr, Deleter del = Deleter()) : ctrl_(new control_block(std::move(del), p)) {}
    shared_unique(shared_unique const& r) : ctrl_(r.ctrl_) { ctrl_->addref(); }
    shared_unique& operator=(shared_unique const& r)
    {
        auto tmp = r;
        swap(r);
        return *this;
    }

    shared_unique(shared_unique&& r) : ctrl_(r.ctrl_) { r.ctrl_ = nullptr; }
    shared_unique& operator=(shared_unique&& r)
    {
        auto tmp = std::move(r);
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    ~shared_unique()
    {
        ctrl_->release();
    }

    void swap(shared_unique& r) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(ctrl_, r.ctrl_);
    }

    void reset(T* p = nullptr)
    {
        std::swap(ctrl_->ptr_, p);
        delete p;
    }

    T* get() const {
        return ctrl_->ptr_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    shared_unique<int> su1(new int(5));
    assert( su1.get() );
    assert( *(su1.get()) == 5 );

    shared_unique<int> su2 = su1;
    assert( su2.get() );
    assert( *(su2.get()) == 5 );

    su1.reset();
    assert( su1.get() == nullptr );
    assert( su2.get() == nullptr );
}
```

The problem is that it is impossible to make this arrangement thread-safe, unless you provide some kind of 'lock' mechanism to keep the pointed-to object alive while it's being accessed.

If you want to know when an object has been destroyed, it's probably better to have it (or its smart pointer) emit a signal when this happens and have the interested observers listen on the slot (or similar).